# URL redirect issue on theme using angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, cookies

I have a problem on redirecting to a specific url on a theme using angular js.
Basically, on the theme, I have a login.html file, which is then supposed to redirect to dashboard.html after it verifies that the user is in the database. If not, it stays on the login page.

I have no problem implementing this functionality. However, I'm trying to implement a session-like feature in which, it retains the variables from the login page when it transfers to the dashboard. Currently, I'm trying to do it by storing the variables inside php $_SESSION through ajax calls.

The login page is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- <html ng-app='login'> -->
<html ng-app="dashboardApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="no-js {{containerClass}}">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor.00b812ba.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.02bb4eb8.css">

</head>
<body ng-controller='loginBodyCtrl'>
<form id = 'redirectToDashboard' ng-submit = 'newDataSource()'>
<label>Username</label>
<input id = 'name' type = 'text' ng-model='formData.name'></input>
<label>Password</label>
<input id = 'password' type = 'password' ng-model='formData.password'></input>
<!-- <input type = 'Submit'> -->
<input type = 'Submit'>
</form>

<form id = 'forgotPassword'>
<label>Forgot your password? Click here!</label>
<input type = 'Submit'>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<script src="scripts/vendor.297ae76c.js"></script> <!-- Script which contains angularjs -->
<script src="scripts/old_app.11997041.js"></script> <!-- Declares cookies -->
<!-- Custom Script for OLD -->
<script src="scripts/old_custom_script.js"></script>
```

The controller for the login page is this (old_custom_script.js):

```
'use strict';

angular.module('dashboardApp')
.controller('loginBodyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) 
// .controller('loginBodyCtrl', ['$cookies', function ($scope, $http, $cookies) 
{

$scope.formData = {name: 'John Smith', password: 'Password'};

$scope.newDataSource = function()
{
$http({
method  : 'POST',
url     : './ajax/checkLoginCreds.php',
data    : $.param($scope.formData),  // pass in data as strings
headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
})
.success(function(data) 
{
console.log(data);
if(data == 0)
{
// $cookies.put('authCookie', 'declined');
console.log('Credentials incorrect.');
}
else if(data == 1)
{
/** if username and password is correct - goes to dashboard **/
// $cookies.put('authCookie', 'approved');
window.location.replace("./dashboard.html");
}
else
{
console.log('Dashboard is currently unavailable.'); 
}
});
};
});
```

The file, old_app.js which contains the controller for the dashboard has this snippet in particular which causes me the problems:

```
angular.module('dashboardApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

$scope.main = {
title: 'Minovate',
settings: {
navbarHeaderColor: 'scheme-default',
sidebarColor: 'scheme-default',
brandingColor: 'scheme-default',
activeColor: 'default-scheme-color',
headerFixed: true,
asideFixed: true,
rightbarShow: false
}
};

$scope.ajaxFaker = function(){
$scope.data=[];
var url = 'http://www.filltext.com/?rows=10&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}&delay=5&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

$http.jsonp(url).success(function(data){
$scope.data=data;
console.log('cecky');
angular.element('.tile.refreshing').removeClass('refreshing');
});
};

$http({
method  : 'GET',
url     : './ajax/checkAuthentication.php',
headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  
// set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
})
.success(function(data) 
{
console.log(data);
if(data == 0)
{
// $cookies.put('authCookie', 'declined');
// console.log('Credentials incorrect.');
window.location.replace("./login.html");
}
else if(data == 1)
{
/** if username and password is correct - goes to dashboard **/
// $cookies.put('authCookie', 'approved');
console.log('Dashboard successfully accessed.'); 
}
else
{
window.location.replace("./login.html");
}
});
});
```

Please note the line with

```
 window.location.replace("./login.html")
```

Everytime this executes, the url redirects to

```
url.../login.html/#/dashboard/app
```

but then the browser **CRASHES**.

I have no idea what is causing this issue since a similar line in old_custom_script.js is working flawlessly. Can anyone help?

Comment: An additional observation that I found out is that it adds hash to the end of the string during the redirect. For example, <url>.../login.html becomes <url>.../login.html/#/dashboard/app. If I can somehow remove this hash after it redirects, maybe that can help me solve my problem.